# I can connect to server but I cannot map in Indusoft Web Studio

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I am using the collaboration feature in Indusoft Web Studio which involves Team Foundation Server 2010.

I made the server, I made the collection and also the team Project. I have successfully also added permissions.

The problem is that when I try to map the connection, Indusoft only tells me that it can connect to the server but it cannot map.

In Visual Studio using Team Explorer, I can successfuly map the folder to the server but I cannot do it in Indusoft.

I understand more information is needed but I dont know what exactly to tell you